# Logstash KV filter help needed

Tags: logstash

I am trying to write a logstash configuration for the following log entry.

```
102.89.98.123,-,"[04/Jun/2018:12:36:44 -0400]",?q= 
(AggrDept:John%20OR%20AggrBeept:Smith)&fq=EmployeeNumber: 
(12345)&fq=PersonIDCd:M&fq=PersonStatusCd: 
(1%20OR%203)&AppCode=1234&wt=json&indent=true&rows=2
```

I have successfully extracted all the parameters into their own fields. I have extracted

```
?q=(AggrDept:John%20OR%20AggrBeept:Smith)&fq=EmployeeNumber: 
(12345)&fq=PersonIDCd:M&fq=PersonStatusCd: 
(1%20OR%203)&AppCode=1234&wt=json&indent=true&rows=2
```

in it's own field called "keys"

I want the following output

```
    AggrDept:John
    AggrBeept:Smith
    EmployeeNumber:12345
    PersonIDCd:M
    PersonStatusCd:[1,2,3]
    AppCode:1234
    wt:json
    indent:true
    rows:2
```

I used the KV filter

```
`kv{
    source => "keys"
    field_split => "&"
    value_split => ":"         
}`
```

However, I am not getting the desired result. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: does your log include line break as well?

Comment: You'll have to split your keys field in two parts, since the `value_split => ":"` won't work for `AppCode=1234&wt=json&indent=true&rows=2`/. Or with filter mutate/gsub 1) remove the `fq=` 2) replace the `=` with `:` so that the same value_split can be used for all the values.

Comment: Sufiyan: The line I provided is an instance from a log file. These instances are separated by a line break. Thanks for your response. I followed your recommended approach but still couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly add

```
include_keys => [
                        "AggrDept",
                        "AggrBeept",aso...
]
```